# Optimize Network Graph creation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, boost

I have the following code that goes through a matrix of 188k x 188k rows of data and attempts to create a network graph out of it. The problem here is my algorithm is extremely slow (as expected since its quadratic). Is there a better way of doing this that I'm not seeing? I'm already thinking of using openMP to parallelize this but would be great if I don't have to.

Here's whats true about my matrix - its symmetric, its over 188 thousand by 188 thousand, each value in the matrix corresponds to the edge weight So for example, an element aij is the weight of the edge between i and j. Here's my code:

The graph creation:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list
<
boost::vecS,
boost::vecS,
boost::undirectedS,
boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>,
boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float>,
boost::property<boost::graph_name_t, std::string>
> UGraph;

typedef UGraph::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef UGraph::edge_descriptor edge_t;
```

Now the function creating the network:

```
    vertex_t u;
    vertex_t v;
    edge_t e;

    bool found=0;
    int idx =0;

    float cos_similarity;
    for(int p =1;p<=adj_matrix.cols();p++){

            //using a previously created vector to track already created nodes
            if(std::find(created_nodes.begin(), created_nodes.end(), nodes[idx]) == created_nodes.end()){
                    u = add_vertex(nodes[idx], ug);
                    created_nodes.push_back(nodes[idx]);
            }else{
                    u = vertex(p,ug);
            }
            int jdx = 0;

            for(int q =1;q<=adj_matrix.cols();q++){

                    if(p!=q){//NO LOOPS IN THIS GRAPH
                            //using a previously created vector to track already created nodes
                            if(std::find(created_nodes.begin(), created_nodes.end(), nodes[jdx]) == created_nodes.end()){
                            v = add_vertex(nodes[jdx], ug);
                    created_nodes.push_back(nodes[jdx]);
                            }else{
                                    u = vertex(q,ug);
                            }


                            tie(e, found) = edge(u, v, ug);

                            if(!found){//check that edge does not already exist
                                    cos_similarity = adj_matrix(p,q);
                                    fil<<cos_similarity<<endl;
                                    fil.flush();
                                    if(cos_similarity >= 0.2609){ //only add edge if value of cell is greater than this threshold
                                            boost::add_edge(u,v,cos_similarity, ug);
                                            edge_out<<p<<" "<<q<<" "<<cos_similarity<<endl; //creating an edge-weight list for later use
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    jdx++;
            }
            idx++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple tip:

1. I think your algorithm is cubic rather than quadratic, because vector and std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end()) are used to avoid duplicates in the inside loop.
2. To avoid duplicates and keep the algorithm quadraic, you can just traverse the upper triangle of the matrix as it's symmetric, which means the graph is an undirected graph.

Comment: That makes sense. I just changed the for loop to traverse only the upper triangle of the matrix. I'll will bring you feedback soon.

Comment: I have converted it to quadratic like you said but its been running for the past 4 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, unekwu. Now let's analyse it for a little bit. Traversing the upper triangle of the matrix wil take N*(N+1)/2 = 188,000 * 188,000 / 2 = 17,672,000,000 loops. According to your feedback, the total running time is more than 4 hours(14400 s = 14400E+9 ns), so each loop should cost more than 814.85ns.

Comment: In your code, I suppose the most time-consuming part is to write file: 'fil<<cos_similarity<<endl; fil.flush();' and 'edge_out<<p<<" "<<q<<" "<<cos_similarity<<endl;'.